# Save images from client in Azure storage

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have the following code. It is not giving me any errors, but I do not have an image in my folder in Azure storage.

```
            var bytes = person.Image.GetBytes();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes.Result);
  var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("AccountName", "***/pEYRskVHuAtUhcvLT/Ct*****/71lLMUCgTybnm****B4WO/AGFe****==");
        var cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, true);
        var cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        var container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("https://*********.blob.core.windows.net/images");

        var newBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myfile.jpg");
        newBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
```

What should I do here? I have empty image in store?

```
private async Task UploadFile(string path,Stream stream)
        {

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=f********ge1;AccountKey=w9S**************==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");

        // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("img.jpg");
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
        using (var fileStream = stream)
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please post more details information about how you call these codes? In a MVC controller method or else?

Comment: You may need to set the position of you memory stream to zero. `ms.Position  = 0;` before you `UploadfromStreamAsync` -- wrote this on @gauarav-mantri comment accidentally.

Comment: In your first block of code, you're passing an entire url to `cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference()` - it should be just the container name.

Comment: ms.Position = 0; It helped me

Comment: Sorry about `ms.Position(0)`. It should have been `ms.Position = 0`. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you're running into this issue is because you're calling an `async` operation and not waiting for it to complete:

```
newBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
```

You could fix this by waiting for this operation to finish using something like:

```
ms.Position = 0;
await newBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
```

or use of `sync` version of the same method:

```
ms.Position = 0;
newBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
```

Comment: I have changed and it is saved. Thank you. But when I try to check it there is 0 B. If I upload image from interface I can see it, but after my code it is like green square and 0B.   
What should I do?

Comment: Just reset the memory stream's position to `0` (`ms.Position(0)`) before uploading and that should take care of the zero byte problem.

Comment: I can not write ms.Position(0)

Comment: You may need to set the position of you memory stream to zero. `ms.Position  = 0;`